# How do I get react to interact with this solidity contract?

Tags: solidity, react

Let's say I have this solidity code:

```
uint256 public num;

  function setNum(uint256 _num) public {
    num= _num;
  }
```

How would I create a react form that passes a value to the smart contract and retrieves the result?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use events. Here is an example:

```
  uint256 public num;
  Event NumberSetted(uint256 num);

  function setNum(uint256 _num) public {
    num= _num;
  emit NumberSetted(_num);
  }
```

You can learn more about it from [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.6.7/contracts.html#events)

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to install and import Web3 and connect your website with the Metamask extension.

The code for connecting your website with Metamask is:

```
if (Web3.givenProvider) {
      const web3 = new Web3 (Web3.givenProvider);
      await Web3.givenProvider.enable();
} else {
        console.log("Please Install Metamask extension");
}
```

After connecting with Metamask, you have to access the methods of your contract.

```
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(CONTRACT_ABI, CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
const accounts= await web3.eth.getAccounts();
```

To interact with your contract function, you can use the async function like this:

```
const updateNumber = async(number) => {
  try {
    const receipt = await contract.methods.setNum(number).send({from: accounts[0]});
  } catch (error) {
    console.log ('error: ', error);
  }
};
```